# How to play mutiple videos file as one in website

Tags: python, html, django, flowplayer

I have implemented rtmp flowplayer and it is playing multiple video as one with the help of flash. But this doesn't work on ipad or iphone.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using video formats that are not supported by iPhone and iPad devices.

`As iOS does not support Flash, videos in Flash format - FLV, F4V etc. - cannot be played on iDevices. Videos deployed on iDevices must be encoded in the MPEG4 Part 10 format using the h.264 video codec.`

http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/ipad.html

Comment: Flowplayer for ipad can play a single video. I want a series of video to be played. Just like rtmp floplayer for ipad. http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html